# Private HLS Live Stream - Generating a preview securely?

Tags: video-streaming, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have a private HLS URL. Users need to register/pay to view the stream.

However, I want to generate a short preview from this live stream so that users can watch a 10 seconds before asking them to sign up.

Is there a way to do this securely (or good enough security) without hosting a separate video?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all you need to do is generate a separate playlist that only contains the preview segments.

Make sure your media segments aren't named sequentially... you don't want to make it too easy to go from segment to segment.